# Почему VS2012express находит ошибки в стандартных заголовочных файлах?!

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Подключил значит #include "wingdi.h"; в Form1.h.Компилирую: более 100 ошибок в wingdi.h. Ошибки в основном синтаксические.

Comment: Возможно не подключен какой-то нужный для `wingdi.h` заголовочный файл. Или не определены или некорректно определены некоторые переменные пре(д)компилятора.

Comment: Проще сразу подключить windows.h, он в свою очередь подключает и wingdi.h.

Answer (score 2):

С очень большой вероятностью, перед включением `#include "wingdi.h";` есть какой то Ваш код или другие включения. И в них ошибка. А так как включения - это просто вставка текста, а анализ идет потом, то и получается вышеуказанное.

Переместите это включение в самый верх (самым первым include). Ошибки скорее всего останутся, но перейдут в более явные места.